# Tooltip inconsistently loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm working on fixing a bug on a web page created in .NET that integrates jQuery UI and uses it to replace the default tooltips generated by the browser.

These tooltips occasionally render in code, as you can see below. Sometimes the tooltip will not render (only when the mouse goes to the center of the button) and then the title attribute will not return to the link element.

This .gif should help illustrate my problem clearly:
[image: jquery-ui hover problem]

I understand why the title element is being removed. It is mentioned by jQuery on their own web page stating that this behavior is expected so that browsers will not render their own versions of tooltips.

The behavior I am confused about is why occasionally the tooltip will not show, and as a result the title attribute is stripped off of my link element.

Even after exploring the jQuery-UI.js source code I still don't understand why the button.hover() doesn't *always* create the tooltip.

Thanks for your help.